# Chart.js max legend height

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

My scenario is:
I'm using phantomjs to generate fixed-size chart images, rendered using chart.js.
I've noticed that when there are too many labels, the legend starts to take up more and more of the availble (fixed) screen space, until the chart is practically invisible, as seen here:
[image: Chartjs chart crowded out by huge legend]
Is there some way to forcibly limit the legend height? Or to set a hard minimum for the chart area height? From debugging and looking at the code here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.6.0/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js and here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.6.0/src/core/core.layoutService.js, I'm not seeing anything useful. Hope I missed something.

Using v2.6.0, and here is the chart definition JSON I'm using:

```
{
  "type": "line",
  "title": "DaTitle",
  "xLabel": "DaLabel",
  "yLabel": "DaYLabel",
  "data": {
    "labels": ["Time0", "Time1", "Time2", "Time3", "Time4", "Time5", "Time6", "Time7", "Time8", "Time9", "Time10", "Time11", "Time12", "Time13", "Time14", "Time15", "Time16", "Time17", "Time18", "Time19"],
    "datasets": [{
      "label": "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR",
      "data": [45, 19, 70, 96, 8, 44, 49, 3, 10, 75, 71, 80, 29, 44, 22, 30, 59, 67, 17, 34]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [9, 60, 19, 71, 4, 47, 14, 35, 44, 2, 92, 8, 89, 73, 98, 15, 3, 41, 81, 20]
    }, {
      "label": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
      "data": [39, 73, 50, 32, 11, 17, 17, 1, 76, 76, 53, 0, 58, 41, 0, 5, 22, 38, 79, 16]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [5, 6, 2, 87, 27, 6, 40, 17, 8, 27, 24, 57, 2, 2, 13, 52, 25, 24, 49, 61]
    }, {
      "label": "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR",
      "data": [72, 73, 82, 71, 0, 37, 31, 22, 88, 63, 81, 22, 63, 54, 89, 30, 47, 49, 5, 77]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [95, 86, 96, 3, 64, 62, 47, 90, 21, 57, 14, 32, 29, 94, 29, 9, 82, 39, 79, 39]
    }, {
      "label": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
      "data": [59, 56, 73, 58, 99, 61, 0, 17, 97, 89, 49, 67, 81, 49, 22, 99, 89, 30, 86, 81]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [5, 72, 51, 40, 97, 56, 40, 13, 0, 60, 65, 86, 58, 95, 67, 84, 4, 48, 37, 36]
    }, {
      "label": "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR",
      "data": [48, 80, 85, 84, 53, 65, 64, 87, 56, 0, 96, 90, 76, 36, 37, 91, 25, 37, 72, 36]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [31, 84, 1, 12, 67, 74, 27, 86, 70, 38, 44, 27, 22, 57, 67, 39, 3, 1, 26, 44]
    }, {
      "label": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
      "data": [70, 66, 99, 63, 99, 26, 3, 71, 28, 91, 81, 28, 70, 46, 2, 57, 84, 51, 77, 15]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [86, 92, 58, 98, 97, 25, 32, 69, 76, 94, 71, 85, 40, 15, 58, 56, 57, 9, 98, 97]
    }, {
      "label": "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR",
      "data": [4, 93, 76, 92, 9, 35, 96, 76, 54, 61, 21, 56, 71, 18, 79, 4, 90, 42, 77, 93]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [78, 16, 40, 44, 11, 23, 93, 63, 94, 78, 57, 77, 75, 15, 63, 21, 12, 59, 56, 99]
    }, {
      "label": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
      "data": [85, 24, 28, 31, 17, 8, 10, 7, 60, 89, 36, 44, 8, 99, 49, 28, 6, 50, 43, 43]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [46, 17, 73, 71, 66, 97, 84, 6, 12, 13, 38, 25, 40, 4, 36, 32, 65, 65, 3, 45]
    }, {
      "label": "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR",
      "data": [92, 43, 10, 40, 19, 34, 12, 48, 64, 89, 62, 61, 37, 25, 33, 31, 93, 83, 13, 16]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [80, 34, 77, 13, 57, 42, 6, 69, 41, 5, 47, 76, 55, 43, 24, 52, 37, 69, 92, 78]
    }, {
      "label": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD",
      "data": [92, 62, 49, 59, 36, 15, 94, 5, 3, 13, 12, 2, 89, 14, 53, 49, 78, 36, 63, 77]
    }, {
      "label": "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
      "data": [79, 42, 90, 42, 75, 49, 96, 33, 53, 18, 63, 44, 27, 87, 92, 89, 30, 27, 72, 5]
    }, {
      "label": "Example",
      "data": [41, 32, 7, 16, 73, 8, 60, 63, 44, 72, 73, 53, 47, 50, 7, 48, 48, 61, 52, 1]
    }, {
      "label": "Linear",
      "data": [87, 91, 61, 80, 97, 19, 99, 93, 88, 17, 94, 79, 64, 87, 36, 75, 82, 53, 39, 84]
    }, {
      "label": "Interpolation",
      "data": [30, 77, 18, 39, 67, 10, 19, 70, 76, 72, 66, 60, 87, 37, 43, 56, 89, 22, 2, 94]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [HTML Legends](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends).

Comment: That could maybe work, I'm currently looking at the very similar method used here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229626/how-to-fix-chart-legends-width-height-with-overflow-scroll-in-chartjs?rq=1
However, I'm very happy with the legend generally, and as you see above I use its point style feature, for color-blind accessibility. I would hate to have to rewrite all of it just to set a maximum height...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to do a stupid little hack to get exactly what I wanted, and it's good enough for me, though it might be a little too hacky for other people's tastes:

```
Chart.Legend.prototype.afterFit = function () {
    console.log('Before afterFit: ' + JSON.stringify(this.minSize) + ' ' + this.height);
    this.minSize.height = this.height = 100;
    console.log('After afterFit: ' + JSON.stringify(this.minSize) + ' ' + this.height);
}
```

console log is:

```
Before afterFit: {"width":1664,"height":527} 527
After afterFit: {"width":1664,"height":100} 100
Before afterFit: {"width":1664,"height":527} 527
After afterFit: {"width":1664,"height":100} 100
```

And the result:
[image: Legend limited in height]

I suppose to do this more cleanly, I should probably extend the Legend to override its afterFit behaviour. Will look into it, and I'll update here if it's possible to do it without too much hassle.

EDIT 19/10/2017:

Here is a "nicer" way to do this, which will look to a user like it was a built-in feature:

```
var origAfterFit = Chart.Legend.prototype.afterFit;
Chart.Legend.prototype.afterFit = function () {
    origAfterFit.call(this);
    if (this.options && this.options.maxSize) {
        var maxSize = this.options.maxSize;
        if (maxSize.height !== undefined) {
            this.height = Math.min(this.height, maxSize.height);
            this.minSize.height = Math.min(this.minSize.height, this.height);
        }
        if (maxSize.width !== undefined) {
            this.width = Math.min(this.width, maxSize.width);
            this.minSize.width = Math.min(this.minSize.width, this.width);
        }
    }
};
```

And example chart descriptor json:

```
{
    "type" : "line",
    "data" : {},
    "options" : {
        "legend" : {
            "position" : "bottom",
            "maxSize" : {
                "height" : 200
            },
            "labels" : {
                "usePointStyle" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```