# Make legend list scroll-able in chartJS

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am converting charts from AnyChart to ChartJS. Legends are covering whole graph area when the list is too large. Is there any way to make legends scroll-able when legend position is 'right'?

```
<div class="chart-container" style="display:none;padding:0px;margin-top:25px;border:1px">
  <canvas id="webGUIChartjs" style="padding:5px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

I've created chart in the above canvas.

Expected (Any Chart Example) :
[image]

Current Result (ChartJS Conversion):
[image]

Comment: I don't think they have any option for that, you can refer the official documentation: https://bitbucket.org/goodera/service-sip-widgets/pull-requests/309

Comment: @SibasishMohanty Can't find in documentation

Comment: That's what I told you, they don't have support for that, you may use a hack by changing the stylesheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix chart Legends width-height with overflow scroll in ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229626/how-to-fix-chart-legends-width-height-with-overflow-scroll-in-chartjs)